# Text On each bar of a stacked bar chart d3.js

Tags: d3.js, label, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I would like to have some text in each bar of a stacked bar in stacked bar chart provided in d3.js library.

Thanks for your help.

I have customized the example here [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) but I have not changed anything else in the javascript code

and here is the result [image: result]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the important piece of code:

```
  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

This binds each `data` point to the colored rectangles. To add text, change it like this:

```
  var ages_enter = state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter();
  ages_enter.append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
  ages_enter.append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d3.format(".2s")(d.y1); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1)+16; })
      .style("stroke", '#ffffff');
```

This stores a pointer to the "enter" method that is called for each data point, then adds an additional element to the svg for each data point.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This only adds text in one bar and I would like to add in both of each bar (the two).

Comment: I have a feeling the issue now is that it is drawing the text and boxes, but drawing the following box on top of the previous text. Svg doesn't have a z-index, it's based on the order that things are appended. I'm on a phone right now but I'll try to run the demo later.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Suspicions were confirmed. The text was showing, but was being displayed below (z-axis) the next bar. I've fixed it by moving the text down 16px.

Comment: The text is a bit cramped when there are a lot of things going on at once. Here's a fiddle from a question I had earlier that may be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/kKvtJ/5/

Answer (score 0):

I plotted out with this code. Text will append into center of the stacked chart . We need to find out the x coordinate values for position the text. For that barWidth/2 is used.[**Demo Sorted Stacked Bar Chart**](http://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/3n8hjybn/3/)

```
 var state= svg.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x(d.state)) + ",0)"; });

  module.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", 200)
  .attr("height", 100) 
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
  .transition()
   .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 200; })
   .duration(4000)
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
   .attr('height', function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); });

 module.append("text")
  .attr("y", 400)
  .attr("x",x.rangeBand()/2 )
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "20px")
  .style("color", "white")
  .text(function(d,i) { return i+1; });
```