# how can i plot 2 dimensional bar chart with a jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, charts

I couldn't find any jquery library that can plot 2 dimensional bar charts (if i name it true). I want to plot a graph like this;

[image]

As you can see there are 2 variable for each bar. Width and height. But i can only change height of the bar charts in every library i tried.
I want to give 2 interval for each variable and plot a rectangle.

Can you help me to find a library that can plot it or share some information about it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use other 3rd party libraries? Have a look at d3.js :
http://d3js.org/

Comment: Yes but d3.js is a big library for takes a long time and i couldn't see any example on d3.js for what i need. It looks like a risky time killer.

Comment: Have a look at this then (may help) : http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with luck. It is called **Marimekko** **graphs** and you can plot it with this javascript library.

http://www.mekkographics.com/free-trial/ or

http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/marimekko_2/

It solves many problems to know its name. You can search for marimekko charts. Also there are lots of free codes in internet like;

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005090

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1005090

[d3.js how do I add text to Marimekko chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967298/d3-js-how-do-i-add-text-to-marimekko-chart)

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/mekkoCharts.html