# Total value on the x axis using Marimekko widget using IBM Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11, marimekko-chart

I am working on a dashboard in Cognos. One of the diagrams in which is a marimekko diagram, as shown below:

[image]

Presently, the widget offers percentage for the entrire diagram. I would, however, like to know how to get the x- axis values of each stacked bar (48.9 thousand - the value of the stacked bar on the very left, 80.2 thousand etc) either below or above as shown in the diagram below? Using summary or KPI widget additoinally either below or at the top, does not solve the issue when the diagram becomes interactive and the width changes.

[image]

The sample data used for producing the marimekko figure is:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can tune your Marimekko visualization by using a [IBM Cognos custom visualization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=visualizations-using-d3-sample-in-your-custom-visualization) and follow this stackoverflow post on Marimekko with [D3.js visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016427/d3-js-how-do-i-rotate-a-marimekko-chart).

The standard Marimekko viz from IBM does not support what you are asking for - data entry slot for sum per bar.